# java mysql не добавляются данные в базу данных

Tags: java, база-данных

сохраняю в базу данных запись, в дебагере даже видно что возвращается ключ созданного элемента, но когда я проверяю базу данных, там нет новой записи
база данных на mysql, соединение с базой работает правильно, id для запроса достаются из бд
использую пул соединений томкэта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private final String SAVE_TICKET = """
                                     INSERT INTO ticket(ticket_no, cruise_id, passenger_id, room_id, state_id)
                                     VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, 1)
                                     """;
    @Override
    public Ticket save(Ticket entity) {
        try(var connection = ConnectionManager.get();
                var prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SAVE_TICKET, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)){
            prepStatement.setString(1, entity.getTicketNo());
            prepStatement.setInt(2, entity.getCruiseId());
            prepStatement.setInt(3, entity.getPassengerId());
            prepStatement.setInt(4, entity.getRoomId());

            var temp = prepStatement.executeUpdate();
            var generatedKey = prepStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(generatedKey.next()) {
                entity.setId(generatedKey.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

если просто ввести в консоли выделенный запрос, то он правильно добавится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD: По-умолчанию в пуле соединений томкэта autocommit выставлен flase, добавил p.setDefaultAutoCommit(true); в настройки пула соединений и всё заработало**

Comment: Чудес на свете не бывает... Проверьте в какую базу пишете, как вариант.

Comment: у меня имя базы данных лежит в properties, на страницах идущих до этой правильно извлекаются данные, нигде в коде параметры подключения не меняются, да и в дебагере верно имя базы выводит

Comment: В настройках соединения указано `connection.setAutoCommit(true)`? Или просто `connection.commit()`.

Comment: ТОЧНО, в томкэте он поумолчанию false оказался!